# How to import SQL file from docker container file system?

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-exec

I have a `docker exec` command that tries to import a SQL dump file but it's complaining about the file not being found.

```bash
docker exec $DB_CONTAINER mysql -u root -ptest < /path/to/database.sql
```

The path is correct (inside the container) but when I investigated why this was not working, I figured that it was trying to look for the file from my host system instead of the container where the file is actually located. How do I import this file and make sure that it looks at the container file system instead of my host file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> docker exec $DB_CONTAINER mysql -u root -ptest < /path/to/database.sql
> ```

The `<` is being interpreted by the shell that's about to execute `docker`.  `/path/to/database.sql`.

> The path is correct (inside the container)

Then the filename has to make it inside the container.  You have a few options:

```
docker exec $DB_CONTAINER sh -c 'mysql -u root -ptest < /path/to/database.sql'
```

Invoke a shell on the container and have the shell handle the redirection to mysql.

```
docker exec $DB_CONTAINER mysql -u root -ptest -e "source /path/to/database.sql"
```

Comment: It was complaining about no database being selected so I modified your script a little bit: `docker exec $DB_CONTAINER mysql -u root -ptest -e "USE my-database; SOURCE /path/to/database.sql"` and I got this error: `ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SOURCE ...`

Comment: Ignore my comment, I just had a missing `;` at the end after the `source` command. Thanks!

Comment: Cheers! [You can also specify db name in the mysql arguments](mysql -u root -ptest) `mysql -u root -ptest my-database -e ...`. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html that's where I got that `source`, by the way.